# How to create horizontal FlatList with multiple rows and items with dynamic width?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, listitem

I want to achieve something simillar to this:

[image]

The effect is similar to UICollectionView from Swift with self sizing cells.

How should I go implementing this in React Native?

Setting `numColumns` will not achieve the desired effect as I need a dynamic number of cells per row. That would limit me to the value of `numColumns`. There should be as many items per row as there can fit. If no more can fit on that row, then add to the next row.

Thanks!

Comment: I managed to show something like that using a standard map and a list of Chips from react-native-elements but the rendering is sluggish, searching for a better solution too.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use the `flexWrap` style. and set the text view a fixed height. the width is auto.

```
<View style={[{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: ' wrap'}]}>
         data.map(element => {
           return <Text style={{height:100}}>element.content</Text>
         })
        </View>
```

Comment: FlatList reuses the items for good memory managemnet. A simple view is not ideal from this point of view.